# $\mathcal{P}(A) \cup \mathcal{P}(B) \subseteq \mathcal{P}(A \cup B)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am stuck and I can't figure out where to go after these few steps. $\mathcal{P}(A)$ means the power set of $A$. Can you lead me in the right direction?
pf. Let $x \in{ \mathcal{P}(A) \cup \mathcal{P}(B)}$. Then $x \in \mathcal{P}(A)$ or $x \in \mathcal{P}(B)$. By definition $x \subseteq A$ or $x \subseteq B$. Then $x \subseteq A \cup B$.

Comment: Then $x \in P(A \cup B)$. Done.

Comment: @aduh Ok, then I restate what I was trying to prove at the end, right?

Comment: There'd be nothing wrong with doing that.

Comment: @aduh thanks. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X \in (\mathcal{P}(A) \cup \mathcal{P}(B))$, by definition of union:
$$X \in \mathcal{P}(A) \lor X \in \mathcal{P}(B)$$
$\implies$By definition of power set
$$X \subseteq A \lor X \subseteq B$$
$\implies$By this teorem; If $X \subseteq A$ then $X \subseteq A \cup B$ (Verify)
$$X \subseteq (A \cup B) \lor X \subseteq(B \cup A)$$
$\implies$Idempotency
$$X \subseteq A\cup B$$
$\implies$By definition of power set
$$X \in \mathcal{P}(A \cup B)$$
Then $\mathcal{P}(A) \cup \mathcal{P}(B) \subseteq \mathcal{P}(A \cup B) \blacksquare$